# using mapbox in android studio with function

Tags: android-studio, mapbox, mapbox-android

I use MapBox in android studio and show a point in map. Now I want to have a function to get a LatLng variable as an input and show that point on the map.(I want to have a function outside of onMapReady, which, with the call of the function, send points to the function as input and within the function, points appear on the map.). Please guide me

```
    private MapView mapView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Mapbox.getInstance(this, YOUR_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull MapboxMap mapboxMap) {

        mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS, new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
        @Override
        public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {

            // Map is set up and the style has loaded. Now you can add data or make other map adjustments



        }
    });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So, Simple. Write below code in `onMapReady` method and Use this `mapboxMap` variable to add the marker point on Map.

```
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(20.5992, 72.9342);
mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).setTitle("set title of marker point"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I want to have a function outside of onMapReady, which, with the call of a function, send points to the function as input and within the function, points appear on the map.

Comment: ok then check this code which i use. **public void addMarker(LatLng latlng, String markerName){
   mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).setTitle(markerName));
  }**     .. and call this funcation like this.**addMarker(latLng, mapsModel.getName());**